# Can't create php register form

Tags: php

[Image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tNTV.png)

Error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\OSPanel\domains\register\signup.php on line 47

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

One more curly brace should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a curly bracket at the end of the PHP code. You need to close your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` So by adding a single `}` before your closing PHP tag, you'll fix this error.

Try lining things up a little better to keep track of what is closed and what isn't.

Comment: On a side note. You should really look into the use of [prepared statments](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). Inserting user input into the database directly is never a good idea.